# Where exactly Riemann surfaces and monodromy groups appear in this video?

Tags: galois-theory, riemann-surfaces, quintics

This is regarding the proof of the unsolvability of the quintic equation (Abel-Ruffini theorem) which is explained really well in this short [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeRXVL6qPk4).

I also understand that the [original proof](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/abel.pdf) by Arnold uses Riemann surfaces and Monodromy groups. I am wondering where exactly the Riemann surfaces pop in this video?

Also, it will be great if someone could intuitively explain what monodromy groups are in the context of this video. Thanks!

Comment: Let $f(z) = z^{1/2}$ pick some $a> 0,f(a)= \sqrt{a}>0$, $f$ is analytic around $z=a$, extend it analytically along the circle of radius $a$, when you have done a full $2\pi$ rotation  you'll obtain $-f$. One more rotation you get $f$ back. The monodromy group of $z^{1/2}$ is $\{ f \mapsto f, f \mapsto -f\} $ the group with 2 elements. You can do the same with $f$ locally analytic and $\sum_{n=0}^5 c_n(z) f(z)^n=0$ with $c_n(z)$ some fixed polynomials. And you can do the same with $\sum_{n=0}^5 c_n(z,y) f(z,y)^n=0$, this time the loops won't be in $\Bbb{C}$ but in $\Bbb{C}^2$.

Comment: For $a,b,c_n(a,b)\in \Bbb{Q}$ the loops $\gamma :(a,b) \to (a,b), f(a,b) \mapsto f_\gamma(a,b)$ will induce the  Galois group of $\sum_{n=0}^5 c_n(a,b) X^n$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I am not sure how this relates to the video, although I kinda get the idea of monodromy group. But I am not sure how does one get a monodromy group with 3 or more elements. So if I have $\sqrt[3]{z}$ and I circle with $2\pi$ rotation, will I have a monodromy group with three elements?